# Example for test files using l3build

Tags: latex3, l3build

After writing some code with LaTeX3 I discovered the ability of [l3build](http://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/l3build/l3build.pdf) to compare a newly produced output to a normalized test output. As it sounds quite useful I tried writing some tests myself and I just didn't (and don't) quite understand it (ergo: I didn't manage to make it work).

Suppose I have the given .dtx file defining

- `\DoubleIt` to print every character twice (`Hello` -> `HHeelloo`) and
- `\ChangeToNumber` (not yet fully written) which will be equal to `\int_from_alph:n` (`x` -> `24`)

Given those macros, how can I define a normalized output file for tests?

`doublefoo.dtx` file:

```
% \iffalse  meta-comment
% !TEX program  = pdfLaTeX
%
%<*internal>
\iffalse
%</internal>
%<*internal>
\fi
\def\nameofplainTeX{plain}
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX\else
  \expandafter\begingroup
\fi
%</internal>
%<*install>
\input l3docstrip.tex
\keepsilent
\askforoverwritefalse
\preamble

\endpreamble
%\postamble


%\endpostamble
\usedir{tex/latex/doublefoo}
\generate{
  \file{\jobname.sty}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{package}}
}
%</install>
%<install>\endbatchfile
%<*internal>
\usedir{source/latex/doublefoo}
\generate{
  \file{\jobname.ins}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{install}}
}
\nopreamble\nopostamble 
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX
  \expandafter\endbatchfile
\else
  \expandafter\endgroup
\fi
%</internal>
%<*driver> 
\documentclass [
        onlydoc,
]{l3doc}

\usepackage{doublefoo}


\begin{document}
\DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%
%
% \CharacterTable
%  {Upper-case    \A\B\C\D\E\F\G\H\I\J\K\L\M\N\O\P\Q\R\S\T\U\V\W\X\Y\Z
%   Lower-case    \a\b\c\d\e\f\g\h\i\j\k\l\m\n\o\p\q\r\s\t\u\v\w\x\y\z
%   Digits        \0\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9
%   Exclamation   \!     Double quote  \"     Hash (number) \#
%   Dollar        \$     Percent       \%     Ampersand     \&
%   Acute accent  \'     Left paren    \(     Right paren   \)
%   Asterisk      \*     Plus          \+     Comma         \,
%   Minus         \-     Point         \.     Solidus       \/
%   Colon         \:     Semicolon     \;     Less than     \<
%   Equals        \=     Greater than  \>     Question mark \?
%   Commercial at \@     Left bracket  \[     Backslash     \\
%   Right bracket \]     Circumflex    \^     Underscore    \_
%   Grave accent  \`     Left brace    \{     Vertical bar  \|
%   Right brace   \}     Tilde         \~}
%
% 
% \GetFileInfo{\jobname.sty}
%
% \begin{documentation}
%
% \DoubleIt {Hello}
%
% \ChangeToNumber {x}
%
% \end{documentation}
%  
% \begin{implementation}
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<@@=doublefoo>
%    \end{macrocode}
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
\@ifpackageloaded {xparse} 
  { } 
  { \RequirePackage {xparse} }
\@ifpackageloaded {expl3} 
  { } 
  { \RequirePackage {expl3} }
%    \end{macrocode}
%    \begin{macrocode}
\ProvidesExplPackage
  {doublefoo}
  {2016/06/31}
  {42}
  {A foo to double up your bar.}
%    \end{macrocode}
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
\NewDocumentCommand \DoubleIt { m }
  {
    \tl_map_inline:nn {#1} { ##1 ##1 }
  }
%    \end{macrocode}
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
\NewDocumentCommand \ChangeToNumber { m }
  {
    %% not yet defined.
  }
%    \end{macrocode}
%
% \end{implementation}
%
% \endinput
```

`build.lua` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env texlua

module = "doublefoo"

unpackfiles = {"*.dtx"}

kpse.set_program_name("kpsewhich") 
dofile(kpse.lookup("l3build.lua"))
```

`testfiles/Versuch.lvt` (pretty much the same as in chapter 2.3 of [l3build](http://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/l3build/l3build.pdf))

```
\documentclass{article} 
\input{regression-test} 
\usepackage{doublefoo} 

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\box_new:N \l_tmp_box 
\hbox_set:Nn \l_tmp_box {\DoubleIt{Hallo}} 
\box_show:N \l_tmp_box 
\ExplSyntaxOff 
\end{document}
```

Next I did the following steps (in the correct directory):

1. Run `texlua build.lua save Versuch`
2. Change in `doublefoo.dtx` the command `\DoubleIt` to

   ```
   \NewDocumentCommand \DoubleIt { m }
     {
       Change
       \tl_map_inline:nn {#1} { ##1 ##1 }
     }
   ```

   and safe the file. (Also compile it to make sure I changed the output.)
3. Run `texlua build.lua check`

Doing that the terminal prints

```
Running checks on
  Versuch

  All checks passed
```

which cannot be true as `\DoubleIt` is different then before.

---

As a side note here is a (correct working, thanks to the answer) test with a `.lve`  file:

`testfiles/Versuch2.lvt`

```
\documentclass{article} 
\input{regression-test} 
\usepackage{doublefoo} 

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\START

\OMIT
\hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { \ChangeToNumber { x } } 
\TIMO

\box_show:N \l_tmpa_box 

\END
```

`testfiles/Versuch2.lve`:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\input{regression-test} 
\usepackage{doublefoo} 

\begin{document}

\START

\ExplSyntaxOn

\OMIT
\hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { 24 } 
\TIMO

\box_show:N \l_tmpa_box 

\END
```

Afterwards for example `texlua build.lua check Versuch2`.

Comment: No relevant to the issue, but I would remove the `\CharacterTable`: this was useful 20 years ago but the team have dropped them from the sources now.

Comment: Nowadays, the `build.lua` file shouldn't contain the lines `kpse.set_program_name("kpsewhich")` and
`dofile(kpse.lookup("l3build.lua"))`. Moreover, the invocation shouldn't be `texlua build.lua` but `l3build` (thanks to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/680684/18401).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is that you've not got any content in the `.tlg` file. The reason for that is you've not told the test system that the 'useful' part of the `.log` has started (there is lots of material in a raw log that you don't want). You need to have `\START` somewhere in the test input to mark the point after which 'useful' material appears. I'd probably go for something like

```
\documentclass{article} 
\input{regression-test} 
\usepackage{doublefoo} 

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\START

\OMIT
\box_new:N \l_tmp_box 
\hbox_set:Nn \l_tmp_box {\DoubleIt{Hallo}} 
\TIMO

\box_show:N \l_tmp_box 

\END
```

here. With a single test we don't necessarily need the `\OMIT` block ( could just move the `\START`), but for a more complex situation might have

```
\documentclass{article} 
\input{regression-test} 
\usepackage{doublefoo} 

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\START

\TEST { Basic~use#of~\token_to_str:N \DoubleIt }
  {
    \OMIT
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box {\DoubleIt{Hallo}} 
    \TIMO
    \box_show:N \l_tmpa_box
  }

...

\END
```

Notice that the code that is part of the test 'set up' but not being tested is inside an `\OMIT` block (in case there is some stray issue elsewhere). I've also used the standard `\l_tmpa_box` as in test files this is 'safe' (there should be no risk of a clash).

Comment: Is there a way to test that an error message is working as expected?

Comment: @Erwann Errors are written to the `.log`, so they will be part of the test output like anything else

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150238/discussion-on-answer-by-joseph-wright-example-for-test-files-using-l3build); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.