# Impossible to run l3build tests

Tags: l3build, packages-testing

I'm in the process of trying to understand how `l3build` tests work.

For this, I created the files of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/329743/18401) and here is my sandbox directory:

```
$ tree
.
├── build.lua
├── doublefoo.dtx
├── doublefoo.ins
├── doublefoo.log
├── doublefoo.sty
└── testfiles
    ├── Versuch2.lve
    ├── Versuch2.lvt
    └── Versuch.lvt

1 directory, 8 files
```

where `Versuch.lvt` is the one [rectified by Joseph Wright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/329767/18401):

```
\input{regression-test}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{doublefoo}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\START

\OMIT
\box_new:N \l_tmp_box
\hbox_set:Nn \l_tmp_box {\DoubleIt{Hallo}}
\TIMO

\box_show:N \l_tmp_box

\END
```

Now, the command `texlua build.lua save Versuch` fails with the error:

> ...ocal/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/scripts/l3build/l3build.lua:157: too many C levels (limit is 200) in main function near 'i'

There's a similar error with the command `l3build save Versuch`:

> ...ocal/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/scripts/l3build/l3build.lua:176: too many C levels (limit is 200) in main function near '"
> "'

Why this test cannot be run and how to run it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not run

```
texlua build.lua save Versuch
```

use

```
l3build save Versuch
```

Also remove

```
kpse.set_program_name("kpsewhich") 
dofile(kpse.lookup("l3build.lua"))
```

Very early versions of l3build required the first form

your `build.lua` just needs one line and can be, in  full:

```
module = "doublefoo"
```

Comment: I added a comment to the linked question in hopes that others won't fall into the same trap I did (edit the question would be even better but I don't know if it would be welcome).