# TeX Output Compare

Tags: compare

Is there a way to compare two LaTeX outputs such as DVI compare or PS compare from the LaTeX utilities?

P.S: Please do not mention the PDF compared with Adobe Acrobat or other PDF tools or with LaTeXDiff TeX file comparison.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329743/example-for-test-files-using-l3build for example

Comment: Can you explain a bit more, what aspects of the output do you want to compare? The text, the layout, the fonts? Or the raw postscript code? Why do you want to compare two versions, what is the goal? Where do the two outputs come from? Why is pdf and/or source comparison not a good solution?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the LaTeX utilities"? And what is the reason that comparing PS documents is okay but comparing PDF documents isn't an option?

Comment: @BanDoP I guess LaTeX utilities are the utilities that are part of a LaTeX distribution, in categories like https://ctan.org/topic/doc-mgmt, https://ctan.org/topic/graphics-prep, https://ctan.org/topic/pdfprocess, https://ctan.org/topic/dvi-print etc.

Comment: Yes, Marijn is correct and PDF compare is not accurate even when math are visually the same in two documents but still the PDF compare highlights for difference.

Comment: Does this mean that, in principle, comparing PDFs would be an option? Could you give more information about what exactly you want to compare? (e.g., the linux tool diffpdf offers to compare either appearance, characters or words, which should already cover a large range of different applications or purposes IMHO)

Comment: Let me say for example I want to compare two files with equations output, one file with equations full of user-defined macro and another file with the same equations with user-defined macro expanded with actual value.

Comment: But that implies that your comparison in fact should take place on the level of the TeX document, no? Example documents would tremendously help to help you...